# Getting a warning when creating UIActionSheet programmatically

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I'm creating a `UIActionSheet` and setting it's delegate to `self` like this:

```
aac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"בחר את הסיבה?"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Everything is working fine.  It's just that I'm getting a warning:

> /Users/shimon_wi/Downloads/TabBarAndNavControllersDemo/Classes/avilability.m:66:63:{66:63-66:67}: warning: sending 'avilability *' to parameter of incompatible type `'id<UIActionSheetDelegate>'`

and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you declared that your class conforms to the `<UIActionSheetDelegate>` protocol? This is done in the header of the class like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

If you don't do this, but you *do* implement the delegate methods, then your code will run but you will get the warning, which sounds like your situation.

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem then please mark it as accepted by clicking the empty checkmark under the answer score. This lets people know the question is answered and gives you a better chance of people answering your future questions.